Unnamed Modules of loader "app" in spring boot Intellij
Class Not found exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: class za.co.fnb.pe.framework.FrameworkSessionContext cannot be cast to class za.co.fnb.st.insurance.ocep.cache.SessionContext (za.co.fnb.pe.framework.FrameworkSessionContext and za.co.fnb.st.insurance.ocep.cache.SessionContext are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
I have created SessionContext class, which extends FrameworkSessionContext which in turns is a inbuild class, when I clean and install the project it is not giving me any error, while executing the code it gives error.

Can you share more details(screenshots and the class you created)?

class has simple variables and getter setter

Ensure that the same class loader loads both FrameworkSessionContext and SessionContext. If they are not, java sees them as separate classes.
Check the runtime classpath with something like this
System.out.println(FrameworkSessionContext.class.getClassLoader());
System.out.println(SessionContext.class.getClassLoader());

I am not pretty sure if it helps or not but try to check these
